# Discretisation of the Perona Malik anisotropic diffusion Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The perona malik diffusion equation mentioned in [this](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~esedoglu/Papers_Preprints/pm_esedoglu.pdf) paper is given as

$I_t = C(x,y,t) \nabla ^2 I + \nabla C . \nabla I$

The discretisation is given as

$I_{i,j} ^{t+1} = I_{i,j} ^{t} + \lambda[c_N .\nabla _N I + c_S .\nabla _S I + c_E .\nabla _E I + c_W .\nabla _W I]_{i,j}^t$

This seems to have missed the $\nabla C . \nabla I$ term. What have I missed?

How is this descretisation reached?

Comment: I've noticed that the spec for the Mathematica implementation of Perona-Malik (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PeronaMalikFilter.html) omits the ∇C.∇I term

Comment: I think this is relevant http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~mwielgus/files/PM_equation.pdf